# Implementing a callback to model.predict in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom layer which gets passed a copy of the input as a parameter like this `x=MyLayer(100,array=input)(input_tensor)`. Then i fit the training examples in a loop one by one so that the particular X value in model.fit is the same as the array 'input'. Input is passed to the layer because it determines which indices in the weight matrix go where. i.e. i have a dynamic weight matrix whose form depends on the input.

The problem comes now in performing a model.predict. how would i pass the input of model.predict to the layer so that it knows where to put which indices before passing the input through the network?

here is some of my code:

```
li = np.asarray(li3)
li = li.astype('float32') / 255.
random_dim = 400
noise = np.random.rand(400).astype(np.complex128)
noise = noise / 0.132174913205638
noise = np.reshape(noise, (1, random_dim))


input_tensor = Input(shape=(random_dim,))

x = MyLayer2(100, array=noise)(input_tensor)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MyLayer2(100, array=noise)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MyLayer2(100, array=noise)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

x = Dense(400, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1 * 32 * 35 * 1, activation='relu')(x)
x = Reshape((1, 32, 35, 1))(x)
x = Conv3D(32, (4, 4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2))(x)

x = Conv3D(32, (4, 4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2))(x)
x = Conv3D(64, (4, 4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((5, 5, 5))(x)

prediction = Conv3D(3, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

modelE2 = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=prediction)
ss = 'pmed.h5'
                                                modelE2.load_weights('/ssd_sda/textfiles/' + ss)
sgd = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=0.1)
modelE2.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='mse')
callbacks = [EarlyStoppingByLossVal(monitor='loss', value=0.04, verbose=1)                                                     
                                                ]


modelE2.fit(noise, li,batch_size=1, verbose=1, epochs=40,                                                              
                                   callbacks=callbacks)
```

For my call method in mylayer i have the following:

```
 def call(self, y):
        li = []
        li2 = []
        li3 = []
        li4 = []
        li5 = []
        li6 = []
        liz = []

        h = -10
        for t in self.array:
            h += 10
            for d in t:
                l = [int(i) for i in str(d) if i.isdigit()]
                if  len(l) < 20:
                    for c in l:
                        c = c + h
                        c = int(c)
                        li6.append(c)

                    for x in range(20 - len(li6)):
                        x = int(x)
                        li5.append(x)
                else:
                    for x in range(20):
                        c = c + h
                        c = int(c)
                        li6.append(c)
                        li5 = []
                li6 = np.asarray(li6)
                li5 = np.asarray(li5)
                li = np.concatenate((li6, li5))
                li6 = []
                li5 = []

                li = np.asarray(li)
                li2.append(li)
            li2 = np.asarray(li2)

        li2 = np.ndarray.flatten(li2)

        li2 = li2.astype(int)
        li2 = np.tile(li2, 20)
        # li2 = li2.astype(int)
        S = tf.Variable(lambda: tf.reshape((tf.gather((tf.reshape(self.w, [-1])), li2)), (400, 400)), trainable=True)

        self._trainable_weights = [S]

        return K.dot(tf.reshape(y, [1, 400]), S)
```

Comment: Could you please provide us more of your code?

Comment: @bjornsing i edited my post to include the information you requested. any ideas?